# Django Form Failure

Tags: python, django

I have the following form:

```
# coding=utf-8

class SelectTwoTeams(BootstrapForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.currentSelectedTeam1 = kwargs.pop('currentSelectedTeam1', None)
        self.currentSelectedTeam2 = kwargs.pop('currentSelectedTeam2', None)
        self.currentfixturematchday = kwargs.pop('currentfixturematchday', None)
        self.currentCampaignNo = kwargs.pop('currentCampaignNo', None)
        super(SelectTwoTeams, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(~Q(fixtureid__fixturematchday=self.currentfixturematchday),campaignno=self.currentCampaignNo)

        if not cantSelectTeams:
            queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1)
        else:
            queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).exclude(teamid__in=cantSelectTeams.values_list('teamselectionid', flat=True))


        self.fields['team1'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['team2'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['team1'].initial = self.currentSelectedTeam1
        self.fields['team2'].initial = self.currentSelectedTeam2

    team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format",'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
    team2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format",'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data # individual field's clean methods have already been called
        team1 = cleaned_data.get("team1")
        team2 = cleaned_data.get("team2")
        if team1 == team2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You picked the same team!")

        return cleaned_data
```

If I use the following in my HTML file and choose the same two teams it correctly says "You Picked the same team!":

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    </form>
```

However, if I use the following:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.team1 }}{{ form.team2 }}
    </form>
```

I get no feedback. Nothing occurs when I choose the same two teams.  Any idea as to why separating the fields stops it from working?

Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between those is not "separating the fields". It is that you have switched from the full form representation - including form labels, layout, and most importantly errors - to only displaying the two input fields themselves.

That's fine to do of course, as for most purposes you will want the extra layout control that it gives you, but you do need to remember to put in all the other things that the basic `{{ form }}` version does.

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.team1.label_tag }}{{ form.team1 }}{{ form.team1.errors }}
{{ form.team2.label_tag }}{{ form.team2 }}{{ form.team2.errors }}
```